# Dealing with warnings in c compilations

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

I have the following warnings during the compilation:

```
solver.c:24: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘mtrx_multiple’ from incompatible pointer type
mat.h:5: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double **’
solver.c:30: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
solver.c:39: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
/tmp/ccmU9zRf.o: In function `vec_norm':
math.c:(.text+0x331): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the lines are:

`solver.c`

```
double *cg_solve( sparse_mat_t A,  double *b,  double *x ) { 

   double *a;
   double **r;
   double *be;
   double **p;
   double **x0;
   x0[0] = vec_copy(x, size);
   ...
   line 24:   r[0] = vec_subtraction( b, mtrx_multiple(A, x0), size );
   line 30:   x0[k+1] = vec_addition( x0[k], vec_numb_multiple(a[k], p[k], size), size ); 
   line 39:   p[k+1] = vec_addition( r[k+1], vec_numb_multiple(be[k], p[k], size), size );
}
```

`math.h`

```
line 5:   double *mtrx_multiple (sparse_mat_t A, double *c);
```

The function that are used there: (`math.c`)

```
double *vec_subtraction (double *a, double *b, int n) { 
    double *result = malloc(sizeof(double)*n);  
    int i;  
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        result[i] = a[i]-b[i];  
    return result;
}

double *vec_addition (double *a, double *b, int n) {    
   double *result = malloc(sizeof(double)*n);   
   int i;   
   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
       result[i] = a[i]+b[i];   
   return result;
}

double *vec_numb_multiple (double a, double *b, int n) {
    double *result = malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
       result[i] = a*b[i];  
    return result;
}
double *mtrx_multiple (sparse_mat_t A, double *c) {
   double *result;
   int i, j;
   result = malloc((A.size) * sizeof *result);
   printf("c.n: %d \n", A.size);
   for (i = 0; i < A.size; i++) {
      int v = 0;
      for (j = A.ia[i]; j < A.ia[i + 1]; j++) {
         v += A.a[j] * c[A.ja[j]];  
      }
      result[i] = v;
    }
    return result;
}

double vec_norm (double *a, int n){
   double result;
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      result =  result + ( a[i] * a[i] );
   result = sqrt(result);
   return result;
}
double *vec_copy (double *a, int n) {
   double *result;
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      result[i] = a[i];
   return result;
}
```

I will be grateful for any help.

EDIT

I found the solution to the x0 problem, thanks Ben. Now what left is:

```
solver.c:30: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
solver.c:39: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
/tmp/ccL4uSoH.o: In function 'vec_norm':
math.c:(.text+0x331): undefined reference to 'sqrt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: THe problem is with the x0 parameter to mtrx_multiple. You need to show how x0 is declared.

Comment: how is declared x0 in solver.c ?

Comment: I have added the declaration of x0 to the question and the function that I'm using to it.

Comment: Now it should be there as well as other variables.

Comment: When you write `mtrx_multiple(A, x0)` are you trying to multiply a matrix and a vector or two matrices?

Comment: matrix and a vector. The matrix is there in Yale format.

Comment: There is a standard C header called '<math.h>'; do not write your own header with the same name.  Treat the names of standard headers as reserved, for your own sanity's sake as well as the sanity of those who ever end up maintaining your code.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you've posted, I'm going to guess that you don't have a declaration for `vec_numb_multiple` in scope before you call it, and the compiler is implicitly typing it to return int; that would lead to the warnings on lines 30 and 39.

The `undefined reference to sqrt()` means you aren't linking in the standard math library; I'm assuming you're using gcc, so you would need to add `-lm` to the command line.

It's a really bad idea to use a standard library file name for your own code (math.h, math.c).

Answer (score 0):

replace (line 24)

```
r[0] = vec_subtraction( b, mtrx_multiple(A, x0), size );
```

with

```
r[0] = vec_subtraction( b, mtrx_multiple(A, x0[0]), size );
```

You said you whant to multiply a matrix (`A` I guess) with a vector, so the second argument must be a vector. `x0` is a pointer to pointers which can be see as a 2D array of doubles, it means a single cell of `x0` is an array of doubles (ie. what you could call a vector). This is why you want to pass x0[0], not just x0 which is : many arrays.

see John's aswer for the rest.